# Cannot get specific value attribute from list of value attributes

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, webdriver

I have a checkbox that I need to control, but first I need to see whether it is checked or not before continuing. The only HTML that seems to change when I click on the checkbox is this: -

```
<input type="hidden" class="final-json" name="defaults" value="
{"force_change_projects":{"enabled":false},"coverage":
{"regions":"coding_only","buffer_length":20},"acmg":
{"enabled":true},"double_user_check":{"enabled":true},"other_coverage":
{"default_depth":20,"coverage":[20],"locked":false}}">
```

The value attribute that I need is `"double_user_check":{"enabled":true}` and each time I click the checkbox the enabled state changes accordingly. I can get the whole value attribute, but I need to get just the  double_user_check attribute from it. I just can't seem to get it though.

So I need to check the enabled/disabled state of the `double_user_check` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `simplejson` library in `python2` or `json` library in `python3`

Use `json.loads(json_data)` to make the json into a python object.
Then use `double_user_check` and `enabled` as an index into the new python object.

```
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json

json_data = """{"force_change_projects":{"enabled":false},"coverage":
{"regions":"coding_only","buffer_length":20},"acmg":
{"enabled":true},"double_user_check":{"enabled":true},"other_coverage":
{"default_depth":20,"coverage":[20],"locked":false}}"""

data = json.loads(json_data)
enabled = data['double_user_check']['enabled']

print enabled
```